# How to include output of help() in sweave pdf

Tags: r, sweave

I would like to include function documentation from the help file in a sweave document. I tried the following sweave block

```
<<>>=
?lm
@
```

but I get error messages when calling `Sweave` on the Rnw file. How can I include the entire help message in the document?

Comment: By "entire help message" you mean everything at `?lm`? If you just want specific portions, you can check out [`helpExtract` from my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/helpExtract.R). The first few lines of the function should also be of interest to you.

Comment: Yes I mean the entire output that gets printed when I call `?lm` (or any other R function). What exactly do I have to put into the sweave chunk to do that?

Comment: Try something like `utils:::.getHelpFile(utils::help("lm"))`

Comment: Or more specifically, `tools:::Rd2latex(utils:::.getHelpFile(utils::help("lm")))`...

Comment: nice, we are getting there. I tried your `Rd2latex` suggestions above inside a sweave chunk with `<<results=tex>>` but I get `Undefined control sequence. \HeaderA` from the `pdflatex` compiler. Do I have to include another latex package?

Comment: I should mention that `gsub("_\b", "", capture.output(tools:::Rd2txt(utils:::.getHelpFile(utils::help("lm")))))` works fine. If you post this as an answer I will accept it. The latex stuff is optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this is really figuring out how to get the information you desire as a character string.

- `help("lm")` opens up the help file for the relevant function, but not in the console.
- `utils:::.getHelpFile` gives you the Rd version of that file.
- From there, you can use `tools:::Rd2txt` to convert it to text...
- Which can be "captured" using `capture.output`.

Those are essentially the steps contained in the first few lines of [`helpExtract` from my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/helpExtract.R). That function, however, captures just the requested section.

Instead, if you can settle for just the text, you can do something along the lines of:

```
gsub("_\b", "", 
    capture.output(tools:::Rd2txt(
        utils:::.getHelpFile(utils::help("lm")))))
```